# fopen throwing Invalid argument error

Tags: c++, windows, fopen

I am having issue with fopen in my C++ project.
I am opening a binary file to write like as follows:

```
wwBool myClass::Open(char* pFileName)
{
    m_pfileHandle = fopen(pFileName, "wb");
}
```

`pFileName` usually contains string like `.\data\filename.ext`.
However, I am getting `Invalid Argument` error in this code.

If I put the filename manually in a `string buffer` and pass it to `fopen` like below:

```
 wwBool myClass::Open(char* pFileName){

   char tempFile[MAX_PATH];
   wsprintf(tempFile, "%s", ".\\data\\filename.ext");

   m_pfileHandle = fopen(tempFile, "wb");
 }
```

it could open the file to write.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a complete compileable example of it going wrong?

Comment: It is in Windows and C++. It is a large project, so not sure how to post a compilable code chunk.

Comment: @YuHao MAX_PATH is Windows specific.

Comment: Yet you say the same filename produces different results. It can't be. How are you checking for errors? What *exactly* ('usually' is bad approach) stored in faulty `pFileName`?

Comment: `wsprintf` is not a standard function. Does it work if you use `sprintf` instead?

Comment: Based on the scraps you have posted, the most likely explanation is just that `pFileName` does not actually point to what you think it does.  You will really have to show some more context or preferably come up with a self-contained example.

Comment: The faulty pFileName contains null.

Comment: Then surely error is expected and problem lies in calling code, which none of us, expect you, could see.

Comment: @Matt after looking into more details, you are probably correct.

Comment: The current directory may not be what you think so that you try to open "c:\Windows32\data\... " or whatever. Or a location in your bin/debug folder.

Comment: Well the problem is resolved. I used _splitpath to get the file name out of it. After I manually got the substring using std::string.find it could write the file correctly. I didn't get the chance to investigate in detail and planning to post the behind the scene reason soon. Meanwhilem if someone can give some explanation, it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Read [fopen, _wfopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) explanation in MSDN carefully.

`fopen` is used only with Unicode support NOT enabled for the project on compilation. `fopen` is automatically replaced by `_wfopen` with Unicode support enabled which means the preprocessor macro `_UNICODE` is defined.

`_wfopen` requires a constant **wide** character string for the file name instead of a constant character string.

Change in your code

```
wwBool myClass::Open(char* pFileName)
```

to

```
wwBool myClass::Open(LPCTSTR pFileName)
```

See [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx) for a description of **LPCTSTR**.

Of course with this change the calling routines must pass a pointer to a `wchar_t` string instead of a `char` or `unsigned char` string which is no problem if the calling routines use also the [Windows Data Types for Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374131.aspx) and not the basic data types.

Comment: Your discussion is also very helpful and relevant!

Comment: This was helpful to me also. I HATE `LPCTSTR`, but I suppose I'll either have to deal with it, or convert it..